# Need to iterate addition/subtraction with LookupSet

Tags: reporting-services, iterator, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-2012

I have a row "A" that has a column "Qty"
I have a row "B" that has a column "Needed" that is to be subtracted or added from "Qty" and placed in another column on row B "Total"

The data in row B is populated using a LookupSet.  So in the "Needed" column, there are n lines of numbers that need to be incrementally subtracted or added.

E.G. Qty in row A is 10, Needed in row B is 1, 2, 5, 2
     Total in row B needs to show 9, 7, 2, 0

Is there a way to utilize SSRS functions to iteratively subtract or add numbers in a lookup set?

Please let me know additional information needed.

[image: Data example]

The 495 is what should be added subtracted from, the blue is what should be subtracted (and example totals).  The second row shows an example of the LookupSet output.

Comment: I think it is possible, but share a complete example of your data and what you are expecting.

Comment: Trying to wrap expressions around the LookupSet function is going to get pretty messy. You'd be better off compiling the data into a usable format on the query side. Provide a sample of how the datasets look if you need help on that front.

Comment: @alejandrozuleta added a drawing.  Does that help?

Comment: @StevenWhite does the drawing help exemplify what the data set looks like?

Comment: @DominicG.Yeah, this should be done in the query, not the report. Your report will end up being unmaintainable if you go down this path.

Comment: @StevenWhite how can I do this in the query? Create a list or something?

Comment: @StevenWhite can I add all the blue numbers together and get a total? That would at least give me something to go off of

Comment: @DominicG. Start by joining the second dataset as a subquery. If you run into a specific problem with that, post a new question showing what you tried and where you're stuck.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following expression in the blue column:

```
=Sum(Fields!Qty.Value, "DataSetName") - RunningValue(Fields!Qty.Value, Sum, Nothing)
```

> Replace `DataSetName` by the actual name of your dataset.

This expression is substracting the running value to the total sum of `Qty` field.

I've recreated a simple example of your requeriment:

[image]

Using the above expression in the highlighted cell I get this:

[image]

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: The "Total" field you reference is not a sum.  It is a different number (aka the running value does not equal the total in all cases).  

Also, how do I code for the second half, since I am using LookupSets?

here is what I have: RunningValue((LookupSet(Fields!PART_NO.Value, Fields!PART_NO.Value, Fields!QTY_REQD.Value, "ShopOrder")), Sum, "ShopOrder")

Comment: @DominicG., What is the column where you are using LookupSet? My solution doesn't require any Lookup function.

Comment: I get the Qty number by using the LookupSet. (5, 10, 5, 10 in your example.)

Comment: `LookupSet` gives you multiple values in an one-dimensional array. How are you getting rows? Maybe converting the array to string and adding End of Line between Qty's?.

Comment: I am not getting rows, it is returning like in the picture I added above.  Is there any way at all to get a runningvalue of the array?

Comment: Conversely, how difficult is converting the array to a string and adding EOL betweetn Qtys? It would be much easier to work with my existing format here, I am at a bit of a time crunch.

Comment: It think it is possible by using custom code. Passing every value of the array and the total as args to the function, for every value the function will return the correct value.

Comment: I just don't think I'm that technically inclined to write that.  Do you know of anyway to even get a sum of the QTYs from the LookupSet? At least that would be of value.